# Как сделать верстку в три столбца?

Tags: php, css, вёрстка

Есть данные с таблицами. Кол-во данных всегда разное. Я получаю данные, вывожу через цикл данные, но они тупо идут в низ. Как сделать так, что бы равноценно делились на три столбца.

```
<div>
<?php foreach ($data as $item):?>

<?echo $item['title']?>;

<?endforeach?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что за данные с таблицами? 
Если я правильно понял Ваш вопрос, то попробуйте так:

```
<div class="block">
    <div style="float: left;width: 33%;">
        <?php foreach ($data as $item):?>
            <?echo $item['title']?>;
        <?endforeach?>
    </div>
<br clear="all" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Надо узнать сколько записей влезет в каждом столбце, а потом их выводить, начиная новый столбец, когда достигли выявленного значения.

Что-то типа такого:

**PHP**

```
$colsQty = 3; // кол-во колонок
$perColumnCount = ceil(Count($data)/$colsQty);
echo '<div class="main">';
for($i=0; $i<Count($data); $i++) {
    $item = $data[$i];
    if (!($i%$perColumnCount)) {
        if ($i>0) echo '</div>';
        echo '<div>';
    }
    echo $item['title']ж
}
echo '</div>';
```

**CSS**

```
.main {
    display: table;
}
.main>div {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Писал в блокноте, но общая идея должна быть ясна:

```
<div>
<?php foreach ($data as $item):?>

     <?echo $strings = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $item['title']) ?>;

<?endforeach?>
</div>
```

[Первоисточник](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-split.php)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?foreach($data as $k=>$v):?>
<?if($k%3 == 0):?>
// Первая колонка
<?endif;?>
<?endforeach;?>

<?foreach($data as $k=>$v):?>
<?if($k%3 == 1):?>
// Вторая колонка
<?endif;?>
<?endforeach;?>

<?foreach($data as $k=>$v):?>
<?if($k%3 == 2):?>
// Третья колонка
<?endif;?>
<?endforeach;?>
```

Comment: три раза крутиться через один и тот же массив?...

Comment: ну я так делаю если нужна разная высота айтемов. циклы в самих колонках.

Comment: да вобщем-то не важно зачем Вы это делаете... Важно то, что Вы три раза проделываете одну и ту же операцию, когда этого можно избежать. Не очень ресурсоемко...

Comment: Ну а если надо 4 колонки? 5... 6... И, кстати, если надо, например, 4 колонки, то Ваш код вставить содержимое 4й колонки и во вторую, и в четвёртую...